# Storage Access Framework user interface

Tags: android, android-storage

How to customize the user interface Storage Access Framework? Really dislike his style. Also in another application I saw an action without this interface. Immediately there was a dialogue about working with the SD card. Advise how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is still possible to use Third Party file browsing libraries or even to write your own (Even on Android 10 you can enable legacy mode)

So most likely these apps they are not using Storage Access Framework(SAF).

But come Android 11 legacy mode is due to be turned off, so these apps not using SAF will stop working.

At the moment with SAF you cannot even customise the orientation of the SAF screens see bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141968218